# Name in json has space and doesn't match with a variable

Tags: php, json

In PHP I do:

```
the_field('country');
```

That gives me: `United States Of America`

In the json I have:

```
"sovereignt": "United States of America",
```

The 2 names should match but they don't, I believe is due to the white space in between the words. The reason why I believe that is that if i check with `"Bolivia"` or `"Canada"` or `"Italy"` I have no problems.

**EDIT**

> I had o instead of O - accepting the answer for future users.

Comment: Check the case : Of != of

Comment: Eh... `O` ≠ `o`...

Comment: Are we to assume based on your latest edit that the capital `O` was a typo?...

Comment: @War10ck damn me, yes it was.

Comment: Also look into: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php then you don't have to convert case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `O` != `o` (i.e. upper vs. lower case). When doing the comparison, try converting both to lower case (using PHP's [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) function):

```
if( strtolower(the_field('country')) == strtolower($json->soverignt) )
```